# How to set a state of a React component based on more than one other states?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-state

I am working on a screen which has a button to record audio. And depending on the state of the recording I'd like to hide a text input box which is on the same screen. To hide it I am changing the opacity and making it not editable.

I am setting 2 states (`isTextInputEditable` and `textInputOpacity`) based on 2 other ones (`isRecording` and `isRecorded`). I am having issues with my current code because useState is asynchronous and the state of isRecording and isRecorded are not updated when I perform the checks in `setTextInputVisibility` function.

Any tips would be helpful, thanks.

```
    const [isTextInputEditable, setIsTextInputEditable] = useState(true);
    const [textInputOpacity, setTextInputOpacity] = useState(1);
    const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState(false);
    const [isRecorded, setIsRecorded] = useState(false);

    const onRecord = () => {
        if (!isRecording) {
            console.log("Started recording audio")
            setIsRecording(true)
            setIsRecorded(false)
        }
        else {
            console.log("Stopped recording audio")
            setIsRecording(false)
            setIsRecorded(true)
        }
        setTextInputVisibility();
    }

    const setTextInputVisibility = () => {
        if (!isRecording && !isRecorded){  
            setIsTextInputEditable(true)
            setTextInputOpacity(1)
            console.log("Text input visible")
        }
        else{
            setIsTextInputEditable(false)
            setTextInputOpacity(0)
            console.log("Text input invisible")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: *"because useState is asynchronous"* - That's exactly what's happening.  If `setTextInputVisibility` should respond to changes to `isRecording` and `isRecorded` then you can make use of `useEffect` to respond to those changes, rather than invoking the function directly.

Comment: Also, why have so many states that are seemingly responsible for pretty much the same stuff? `isTextInputEditable` & `textInputOpacity` seem to depend upon each other, so why not leave just `isTextInputEditable` and then use it to determine both if the input is editable and it's opacity value? You'd probably be able to find a better abstraction for both recording states as well. Basically, avoid adding redundant states unless there is any clear justification for their separation.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is **not** caused by the asynchronous nature of state, but rather the conflicting conditions:

```
if (!isRecording && !isRecorded){ ... } // this is the problem
```

Previously, in the `onRecord` function, you set `isRecording` and `isRecorded` as such:

```
setIsRecording(true)
setIsRecorded(false)
// or the other way around
```

This cause `!isRecording && !isRecorded` never evaluate to `true`, because, there will always be the case that either one of them to will be `false`! So `isTextInputEditable` and `textInputOpacity` will always be false and 0!

##### Possible fix:

```
const setTextInputVisibility = () => {
  if (!isRecording) { // <- only depends on one state condition
    setIsTextInputEditable(true);
    setTextInputOpacity(1);
    console.log("Text input visible");
  } else {
    setIsTextInputEditable(false);
    setTextInputOpacity(0);
    console.log("Text input invisible");
  }
};
```

Again, as tomleb rightful pointed out in the comment, how to manage state is the real issue here, for instance, you may not need `textInputOpacity` state at all, since it is basically the same as `isTextInputEditable`, and they both serves the same purpose.

Check out [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-violet-71f0i6?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use state for hiding text input
since hiding text input is dependent on `isRecording` and `isRecorded`

You can do something like this

```
    const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState(false);
    const [isRecorded, setIsRecorded] = useState(false);

    const onRecord = () => {
        if (!isRecording) {
            console.log("Started recording audio")
            setIsRecording(true)
            setIsRecorded(false)
        }
        else {
            console.log("Stopped recording audio")
            setIsRecording(false)
            setIsRecorded(true)
        }
        setTextInputVisibility();
    }

    const isTextInputEditable = !isRecording && !isRecorded
    const textInputOpacity = (!isRecording && !isRecorded) ? 1 : 0


    return (
        <View>

            {/* Your code goes here */}

            <TextInput 
                disabled={!isTextInputEditable}
                style={{ ...styles.inputStyles, opacity : textInputOpacity }}
            />

        </View>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers which have helped me understand what was going on.

As mentioned by @Enfield, the problem was not the asynchronous nature of UseState. Some conditions were wrong and I had too many states defined which were unnecessary.

I solved it by using only one state which makes use of an enum for the different cases which comes in handy for conditional rendering. Then, as @poojan suggested, I base my text input visibility variables on the recording state I previously created. No need for useEffect here for re-rendering.

You can find a working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-o20pxk?file=/src/App.tsx)

```
enum RecordingStatus {
  RECORDING = "recording",
  RECORDED = "recorded",
  NOTRECORDED = "notRecorded",
  PLAYING = "playing"
}

export default function App() {
  const [recordingStatus, setRecordingStatus] = React.useState<RecordingStatus>(
    RecordingStatus.NOTRECORDED
  );
  const isTextInputEnabled = recordingStatus === RecordingStatus.NOTRECORDED;
  const textInputOpacity = isTextInputEnabled ? 1 : 0;

  const onRecord = () => {
    if (recordingStatus === RecordingStatus.NOTRECORDED) {
      console.log("Started recording audio");
      setRecordingStatus(RecordingStatus.RECORDING);
    } else if (recordingStatus === RecordingStatus.RECORDING) {
      console.log("Stopped recording audio");
      setRecordingStatus(RecordingStatus.RECORDED);
    } else if (recordingStatus === RecordingStatus.RECORDED) {
      console.log("Audio playing");
      setRecordingStatus(RecordingStatus.PLAYING);
    } else if (recordingStatus === RecordingStatus.PLAYING) {
      console.log("Audio stopped");
      setRecordingStatus(RecordingStatus.RECORDED);
    }
  };

  const onCancel = () => {
    console.log("Cancel recording");
    setRecordingStatus(RecordingStatus.NOTRECORDED);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>isTextInputEditable: {isTextInputEnabled ? "true" : "false"}</div>
      <div>textInputOpacity: {textInputOpacity}</div>
      <div>recordingStatus: {recordingStatus}</div>
      <button onClick={onRecord}>change</button>
      <button
        disabled={!(recordingStatus === RecordingStatus.RECORDED)}
        onClick={onCancel}
      >
        cancel
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```